# Custom Lint Rules - JavaScanner @Deprecated

Tags: java, android, google-api, lint, android-lint

I would like to write some custom lint rules for my company android project. I was reading a few tutorials and successfully created a sample rule.

Problem is that I was using a *@Deprecated JavaScanner* API. I was reading official google doc [located here](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/writing-a-lint-check) but it's not up to date. 
I tried to dig into exisiting rules, found [this google git repository](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/android-m-preview/lint/libs/lint-checks/src/main/java/com/android/tools/lint/checks) but it also uses deprecated APIs. So my questions are

**1) Is there any up to date documentation out there, but I just simply can not find it?**

**2) Is there git repository of current lint rules available? So I could analise it?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've already found an JavaScanner replacement. It does not anwser 2 questions I've asked bellow but it solves deprecation interface problem so I have decided to post an answer.

According to this google groups - API changed twice since *JavaScanner*.

First change was to *JavaPsiScanner* but they 
"didn't advertise this widely, since I already knew that we wanted to switch over to UAST (which was still in development)"

Second and final change is to **UastScanner. So one should use it now for Java Classes.**

You can even find short [documentation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/lint-dev/deprecated%7Csort:date/lint-dev/7nLiXa04baM/9q6QJpmODgAJ) writen by Tor Norbye (7th comment from above)

**Edit:** [Sample UastDetector class](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-custom-lint-rules/blob/master/android-studio-3/checks/src/main/java/com/example/lint/checks/SampleCodeDetector.java)

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to implement Custom Rules in Android Projects is by using the Regex-based linting tool [AnyLint](https://github.com/Flinesoft/AnyLint). It's written in Swift though and therefore it only works on macOS and Linux at the moment (Windows support is [in the works](https://forums.swift.org/t/adding-support-for-windows-as-a-platform/30158)). But you don't really need Swift knowledge to use it, just follow it's documentation.

It's the **easiest and fastest way** to implement custom rules for any language, basically and supports **example validation** and even **autocorrection**.

For example, you could write a custom rule to prevent multiple empty lines like so (supports autocorrect):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/swift-sh
import AnyLint // @Flinesoft ~> 0.6.0
try Lint.logSummaryAndExit(arguments: CommandLine.arguments) {
    // MARK: - Variables
    let kotlinFiles: Regex = #"^app/src/main/kotlin/.*\.kt$"#
    let javaFiles: Regex = #"^app/src/main/java/.*\.java$"#
    let xmlFiles: Regex = #"^app/src/main/res/.*\.xml$"#
    let gradleFiles: Regex = #"^.*\.gradle$"#

    // MARK: MultilineWhitespaces
    try Lint.checkFileContents(
        checkInfo: "MultilineWhitespaces: Restrict whitespace lines to a maximum of one.",
        regex: #"\n( *\n){2,}"#,
        matchingExamples: ["}\n    \n     \n\nclass", "}\n\n\nvoid"],
        nonMatchingExamples: ["}\n    \n    class"],
        includeFilters: [kotlinFiles, javaFiles, xmlFiles, gradleFiles],
        autoCorrectReplacement: "\n\n",
        autoCorrectExamples: [
            ["before": "}\n    \n     \n\n    class", "after": "}\n\n    class"],
            ["before": "}\n\n\nvoid", "after": "}\n\nvoid"],
        ]
    )
}
```

I hope this helps.